# how to cut data from in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

i have a table with data and particular column where i need to cut data e.g.:

```
on unknown id:138702 client_type:0 contract:25369/NBX1/010322
```

so i need to cut only `138702`

i tried to use `SUBSTR` but the thing is that besides the example above there is also:

```
 on CALL3 id:138702 client_type:0 contract:25369/NBX1/010322
 on SOPP6 id:138702 client_type:16 contract:25369/JMZXH3/010322
```

so results are kinda messy.

id appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses **[REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html)** function such as

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(.*id:)(\d+).*','\2') AS id
  FROM t
```

which finds the digits just after `id:` upto the digits end by `+` operator which matches all occurences for the digits where whole pattern divides the strings into two parts.The first part starts from the beginning upto `id:`, and the rest(`\2`) is id value

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e480d1a4b52f5aee8b81d985a69cb6fd)</kbd>

Comment: hello, thank u so much for your help. If u dont mind i want to ask u additional qn. after cutting required data i need to convert it to number lets call this table as tab. 
let me explain it more clear so u could understand
i have another table called client_id with ID column, so i need to connect client_id with  tab by ID 
i hope i could explain it to you.

Comment: Hello @SoneHeart , sure you can wrapping the expression by `TO_NUMBER()`

Comment: let me explain it more clear so u could understand. lets call the table that we cut data from as tab. so i have another table called client_id with ID column, so i need to connect client_id with tab (that already cut data)by ID 
i hope i could explain it to you.

Comment: Seems that you need `INSERT INTO t2(id) SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(.*id:)(\d+).*','\2')) FROM t`, don't you @SoneHeart ( indeed, `TO_NUMBER()`, which just verifies the numeric data type , would be redundant in this case )

Comment: not actually(?), 
`select c.id, 
to_number (ltrim(regexp_substr(ba.param, 'id:\d+'), 'id:')) res, 
 ba.user_name


from audit ba, clients c
where ba.description like '%LC%'
and ba.day >= to_date ('01032022','ddmmyyyy')
and ba.day <  to_date ('01042022','ddmmyyyy')
and c.id = res`
ive tried something like this. but for sure it wont work

Comment: also ive tried this
`select c.id, 
(select to_number (REGEXP_REPLACE(ba.param, '(.*id:)(\d+).*','\2')) res,ba.day dd, ba.description d  from audit ba )res1,
 ba.user_name

from audit ba, clients c
where res1.d like '%LC%'
and res1.dd >= to_date ('01032022','ddmmyyyy')
and res1.dd <  to_date ('01042022','ddmmyyyy')
and res1.res(+) = c.id`
but didnt work either 
got a [1]: ORA-00904 error

Comment: Presumably you mean this `SELECT c.id, a.user_name
  FROM audit a
  LEFT JOIN clients c
 WHERE a.description LIKE '%LC%'
   AND a.day BETWEEN date'2022-03-01' AND date'2022-03-31'
   AND TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(a.param, '(.*id:)(\d+).*', '\2')) = c.id` @SoneHeart

Comment: thank u soo much. 
but apparently when i use `LEFT JOIN` i got an error: [1]: ORA-00905
how else i could use joins in it?

Comment: you're welcome @SoneHeart but you have better asking a new question which will clearly state what exactly your need with sample data and desired result as a [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a first numeric value that follows the `id:` string, then this might be one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'on unknown id:138702 client_type:0 contract:25369/NBX1/010322'  from dual union all
  3     select 'on CALL3 id:138702 client_type:0 contract:25369/NBX1/010322'    from dual union all
  4     select 'on SOPP6 id:138702 client_type:16 contract:25369/JMZXH3/010322' from dual
  5    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  6  select col,
  7    ltrim(regexp_substr(col, 'id:\d+'), 'id:') result
  8  from test;

COL                                                            RESULT
-------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
on unknown id:138702 client_type:0 contract:25369/NBX1/010322  138702
on CALL3 id:138702 client_type:0 contract:25369/NBX1/010322    138702
on SOPP6 id:138702 client_type:16 contract:25369/JMZXH3/010322 138702

SQL>
```

Comment: i already love u! thank u so much it worked!